# How to mark HTML tags in a javascript string variable

Tags: javascript, html

Must be real simple but i can't find it :(

I have a javascript string variable in which i had text/String on a array iteration.

```
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var myString += array[i];
}
```

and i only wish to add some HTML tags to display this properly in a HTML page, so something like this:

```
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var myString += '<p>' + array[i] + '</p>';
}
```

I have tried this and the result i get is not recognized as HTML but plain text so :`<p>value</p>`.

I am looking for the answers and since i want to add a lot of formating i also wonder if there is some generator out there to add the proper mark up.

Comment: Your string is just a string. For it to be recognised as HTML or plain text, you have to do something with it. You haven't shared the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Your string to append must be in quotes.And then use innerHTML to set the value.

Comment: thx for quick answer, i missed some key words to find it